# Changing one WebView from another WebView in JavaFX

Tags: webview, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I currently have two WebViews(say leftWebView and rightWebView) inside a horizontal SplitPane which is embedded inside the Anchor Pane. Each WebView has a JavaScript (creating a rectangle with different colors). Now what I want to do is that on clicking one rectangle, I would like to change the other WebView. A simple way to ask this question is how do I invoke the leftWebView by a change in rightWebView.

The UI of my application would look something like this : [Sample Application](http://tinypic.com/r/2utrers/8)

Following are the FXML, Controller and Java Files

```html
public class Demo2 extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

```html
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
   
    @FXML
    private LeftWebView wvLeftWebView ;
    
    @FXML 
    private RightWebView wvRightWebView ;
    
    
    @FXML 
    public void myCustomAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("mCustomAction(): Caught an event ");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }                
}
```

The LeftWebView and RightWebView class are similar, except the changes in the javascript

```html
public class LeftWebView  extends Region{
     
      WebView webView = new WebView();
      WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
     
      public LeftWebView(){
         
          // final URL urlHello = getClass().getResource("TimeGraph.html");
          // webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());
          
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> p, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                        win.setMember("javaObj", new Bridge());
                        System.out.println("LeftWebView(): Constructor");
                    }
                }
            }
        );        
        webEngine.loadContent(
            "<div style='width: 100; height: 100; background: green;' " +
                "onclick='javaObj.clickLeft();' />"
        );
        getChildren().add(webView);
        
    }
          
     
      @Override
      protected void layoutChildren(){
          double w = getWidth();
          double h = getHeight();
          layoutInArea(webView, 0, 0, w, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
          // layoutInArea(toolbar, 0, h-toolbarHeight, w, toolbarHeight, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
      }
     
}
```

```html
public class Bridge {
    public void clickRight() {
        System.out.println("Bridge.clickRight() called");
    }
    
    public void clickLeft() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Bridge.clickLeft() called");
        
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> p, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                        win.setMember("javaObj", new Bridge());
                        System.out.println("Bridge.clickLeft(): property Changed of LeftWebView");
                    }
                }
            }
        );        
        webEngine.loadContent(
            "<div style='width: 200; height: 200; background: blue;' " +
                "onclick='javaObj.test2();' />"
        );
        
        

        /*
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        Pane p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml").openStream());
        FXMLDocumentController fooController = (FXMLDocumentController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        */
        
        /*
        URL location = getClass().getResource("MyController.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());

        // How to get the handler for a specific element of my FXML
        */
        

    
    }
}
```

```html
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import demo2.RightWebView?>
<?import demo2.LeftWebView?>
<?import demo2.FXMLDocumentController?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="demo2.FXMLDocumentController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.4765886287625418" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"                
               prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" >
      <items>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
             <children>
                <LeftWebView id="webLeft" fx:id="wvLeftWebView" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" onAction="#myCustomAction" />
             </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
             <children>
                <RightWebView id="webRight" fx:id="wvRightWebView" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" />
             </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

I am able to callback one of the methods in class Bridge (Bridge.clickLeft()) through Javascript but I am not sure how to go about and access the other WebView and update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to this through the other questions [Changing the text of a label from a different class in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308065/changing-the-text-of-a-label-from-a-different-class-in-javafx) and [Changing JavaFX label using Javascript callback method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332740/changing-javafx-label-using-javascript-callback-method)

The FXML file contains two web views and a label (label just to show a JavaFX control)

```html
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="webviewlabel.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="wvSample" layoutX="184.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="175.0" />
      <WebView fx:id="wvAffected" layoutY="39.0" prefHeight="177.0" prefWidth="154.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lblSample" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the controller class contains

```html
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Label lblSample;
    
    @FXML
    private WebView wvSample;
    private WebEngine webSample ;
    
    @FXML
    private WebView wvAffected;
    private WebEngine webAffected ;
    
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // wvSample = new WebView();
        initiateWebSample();
        initiateWebAffected();
    }   
    
    public void initiateWebSample() {
        webSample = wvSample.getEngine();
     
        webSample.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> p, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject win = (JSObject) webSample.executeScript("window");
                        win.setMember("javaObj", new Connector(FXMLDocumentController.this));      
                        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.initiateWebSample(): Called");
                    }
                }
            }
        );        
        webSample.loadContent(
            "<div style='width: 50; height: 50; background: yellow;' onclick='javaObj.Connecting();' />"
        );
    }
    
    public void initiateWebAffected() {
        webAffected = wvAffected.getEngine();
     
        webAffected.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> p, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject win = (JSObject) webAffected.executeScript("window");
                        win.setMember("javaObj", new Connector(FXMLDocumentController.this));      
                        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.initiateWebAffected(): Called");
                    }
                }
            }
        );        
        String strJScript = "<div style='width: 50; height: 50; background: blue;' onclick='javaObj.Connecting();' />" ;
        webAffected.loadContent(strJScript);
    }
    
    public void setLabelText(String text)
    {
        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.setLabelText(): Called");
        lblSample.setText(text);
    }    
    
    public void changeWebViewAffected(String pstrColor) {
        String strJScript = "<div style='width: 50; height: 50; background: "+pstrColor+";' onclick='javaObj.Connecting();' />" ;
        webAffected.loadContent(strJScript);
    }
}
```

And the connecting class contains the method to call

```html
public class Connector {
    
    private final FXMLDocumentController controller ;

    public Connector(FXMLDocumentController controller) {
        this.controller = controller ;
    }
        
    public void Connecting() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Connector.Connecting(): Called");            
            controller.setLabelText("Bye World");
            controller.changeWebViewAffected("green");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```