# Changing the text of a label from a different class in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529482/javafx-change-label-text-from-another-class-with-controller) but was not able to find any answers. I have reproduced a similar situation where I would like to change the text of a label from another class using the controller

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.#handleButtonAction");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
        Connector.Connecting();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    public void setLabelText(String text)
    {
        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.setLabelText(): Called");
        label.setText(text);
    }

}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="demo5.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Demo5.java

```
public class Demo5 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Connector.java

```
public class Connector {
    public static void Connecting() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Connector.Connecting(): Called");

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(FXMLDocumentController.class.getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            FXMLDocumentController controller = (FXMLDocumentController) loader.getController();

            controller.setLabelText("Bye World");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output at Console**

```
Connector.Connecting(): Called
FXMLDocumentController.setLabelText(): Called
```

But could see no changes in the label. Am I missing something major here ?

Comment: Please see this post for ways you can [revive an unanswered question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-re-ask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change your Connector class to receive the Controller instance:

```
public class Connector {
    public static void Connecting(FXMLDocumentController controller) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Connector.Connecting(): Called");
            controller.setLabelText("Bye World");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.#handleButtonAction");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
        Connector.Connecting(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    public void setLabelText(String text)
    {
        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.setLabelText(): Called");
        label.setText(text);
    }

}
```

**Note:**

If your Connector is going to take longer to execute whatever it needs to, you might want to use a Task, so you don't freeze your UI. To update the Label, you have to bind the text property and then update the Text value using the `updateMessage()` method.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.#handleButtonAction");
        label.setText("Hello World!");

        Task<Boolean> connectorTask = new ConnectorTask();
        label.textProperty().bind(connectorTask.messageProperty());
        connectorTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            // this is going to be called if the task ends up without error
            label.textProperty().unbind();
        });
        new Thread(connectorTask).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    //public void setLabelText(String text)
    //{
    //    System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.setLabelText(): Called");
    //    label.setText(text);
    //}


    public class ConnectorTask extends Task<Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            // ... do whatever you need here

            // then you call this method to update the TextProperty from the Label that was bound.
            updateMessage("Bye World");

            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If we assume that there is a WebView instead of a button with Javascript running and I would like to invoke the FXMLDocumentController.setLabelText() through JS("<div style='width: 100; height: 100; background: green;' " +         "onclick='javaObj.Connecting();' />"). In this case what would be the way to pass the instance of FXMLDocumentController such that the changes are seen on the scene?
I am adding something like this in the listener of WebEngine - 
JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window"); win.setMember("javaObj", new Connector());

Answer (score 1):

Your Demo5 class and Connector class are both creating unique instances of the FXMLDocumentController via the call to `FXMLLoader.load()`. The instance in the Demo5 class is being placed in the scene graph and becomes visible. The instance in the connector is not being made visible. When you call setLabelText() it is changing the text for an unseen label. What you may want to do is get the FXMLDocumentController instance in Demo5 and provide it to the Connector class through the constructor or a setter method. You may need to change some things around depending on what the Connector class is used for. Alternatively, you could use the connector class to load the FXML root and controller and provide methods for accessing them, then use those methods in Demo5 to make the scene visible.

Answer (score 1):

I made it in a simple way by defining the Label as static in the FXMLDocumentController.java:

```
@FXML GridPane myGridPane;
public static Label totLabel = new Label("Total");
```

and add it to myGridPane in the initialize method of FXMLDocumentController class:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    myGridPane.add(totLabel, 0, 3);
}
```

and at any other class you can call the setText() of this label like this:

```
String message = "this message will appear in the total label";//your string
FXMLDocumentController.totLabel.setText(message);
```